# pass a string variable in an sql query executed using EXEC sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

how do I can pass a string variable in an sql query to be excuted using EXEC `sp_executesql`?

the original and working query is:

```
update database01.dbo.Docs SET property1 = NULL where [name] like 'doc.xls'
```

I need to build this query to look like:

```
DECLARE @FileName   NVARCHAR(30),
        @Query      NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @fileName = 'doc.xls'
SET @Query = 'update database01.dbo.Docs SET property1 = NULL where [LeafName] like ' + @FileName
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Many thanks for support.

Regards

Comment: why do you need sp_executesql. you should do this.
update database01.dbo.Docs SET property1 = NULL where [name] like @param

Comment: Hi, 

I need it so I can reuse the query with different values depending on the needs.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use dynamic sql here. You just need to use a parameter for FileName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given query you don't need dynamic SQL... but you should be using parameters if you want to do it.

Heres the link do the documentation: [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
DECLARE @FileName   NVARCHAR(30),
        @Query      NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @fileName = 'doc.xls'
SET @Query = N'update database01.dbo.Docs SET property1 = NULL where [LeafName] like = @File';       

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query,N'@File NVARCHAR(30)', @File = @fileName;
```

Comment: Hi mxix,
working very fine! thanks for answer and support.
Regards